# React Native | Scroll doesn't happen on Android Emulatour

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

I have the following code:

```
  // components
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Dashboard></Dashboard>
      <MainBottomNavBar></MainBottomNavBar>
    </SafeAreaView>
  </ScrollView>
```

```
  // styles
  contentContainer: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  container: {
    marginTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
```

The scroll works perfectly on ios real device, but when I try to scroll on Android emulator - the scroll doesn't happen. However, when I reload the app I see a little movement at the moment when the screen mounts. So that I guess that code is ok, but the problem is with Android Emulator. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? How to make it scrollable also on Android Emulator?

Comment: try to add style={{flex: 1}} to Scrollview

Comment: @FrancescoClementi I tried, but it changed nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't have the bounce feature, only iOS has it:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#alwaysbouncevertical-ios

So the content of android will scroll only if the height is bigger than the container.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little experiment and figured out the following: IF the content of the screen IS LESS than screen - then scroll is blocked somehow on Android Emulator. But IF you EXCEED the screen size - then the scrolling starts working.

Comment: android simply doesn't have the bounce feature, only iOS has it

Comment: @FrancescoClementi thx, now I got the reason. Please, make you comment an answer, so I can mark it as a solution

Comment: Did it, Thanks!